# Get task status in next step

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a task `Maven@3` that is running my tests and I would like to get its status in a next task. Is there a variable to get it ?

For example :

```
  - task: Maven@3
    displayName: UnitTest
    name: UnitTest
    inputs:
      ...maven options...
      goals: 'test'
  - script: echo $(succeeded('UnitTest'))
```

In the script steps, I would like to print the UnitTest Task status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is to use multi job pipeline to separate UnitTest task in a separate job and other jobs dependent on it. Then you can use expression `$[ dependencies.A.result ]` to get the UnitTest status. Please check below example:

```
jobs:

- job: A
  pool: 
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
    - checkout: none  #use checkout step to void syncing repo

    - task: Maven@3

- job: B 
  dependsOn: A
  condition: always()
  variables:
    testStatus: $[ dependencies.A.result ]
  steps:
    - script: echo $(testStatus)
```

You can also [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Click a suggest a feature and choose Azure devops) for supporting variable to get Task status to Microsoft Development team.

Update:

Use Azure devops rest api to get Task status. Below is the scripts:

```
- powershell: |  
    $url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=5.1"

    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $(system.accesstoken)"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get

    $taskResult = $result.records | where {$_.name -eq "UnitTest"} | select result

    echo $taskResult 
  condition: always()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tested it and it doesn't work if there are more than one tasks in my job. For example, the first task failed and set the Agent JobStatus to failed and then the second task succeeded but the Agent Job Status is still mark as failed.

Comment: Hi @victorgallet I updated above answer, please check it out.

Comment: Hi @victorgallet Did yo check out above workaround? Could it serve as the answer to your question?

Comment: I'm testing it. In fact, it doesn't work with several tasks. For example, my first task is failing so it goes to the script with `failed()` condition. Then, the second task succeeded and it still goes to the script with `failed()` condition.

Comment: Yes you are right, The first workaround didnot work for several tasks. Could you try using multiple jobs as workaround.

Comment: I can use multiple jobs but how to avoid checkout step ?

Comment: You can use step `- checkout: none' to void checkout repo. Please check above updated anser.  Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#specify-multiple-repositories) for more information

Comment: Do you think it's possible to get task status by calling Azure API ? Like in this answer : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/943212/get-task-status-in-next-task.html

Comment: Yes i tested the api. it was working. Using azure api to get the task status is a better way. I changed a little bit of the scripts in the answer you mention. Please check it out.