# Can yaml tasks in a pipeline read and write historic data?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am thinking about way of speeding up certain parts of our CI pipeline and came across a question that is not clear to me.

Given a scenario where I have to re-run a certain build on the *same* commit because of e.g. flaky tests, deployment errors or things later down the stream. All this requires some steps to always repeat, e.g. building code or run static code analysis again.

Also given: We retrigger the build from a pull request so we *cannot* manually disable certain steps like static code analysis.

**My question is**: Can I write a task that can report and query its state persistent over all build agents, without rolling my own cache?

ADO does this for instance when showing what "*new*" tests have failed compared to a previous run. To be able to detect "new" ADO needs a notion of a result cache that is stored on the server and be accessible.

What I am trying to evaluate is: Can I create a task that for instance queries a *global* ADO cache for e.g. `"did for commit hash 424de2 static code analysis complete?"` (Regardless on which build agent I currently am)

Comment: Interesting idea. Are you using yaml pipelines? If so, have you looked at the Cache task?

Comment: `We retrigger the build from a pull request so we cannot manually disable certain steps like static code analysis.` this is not true. If you retrigger your build manually you can create such pipeline to skip some steps.

Comment: @bryanbcook afaik cache task is per agent only (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/cache?view=azure-devops-2019), or am I wrong?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej we queue the build from the pull request page. On ADO 2020 on premise there is no way known to me to configure anything except running the build again with its default settings.

Comment: There is nothing in the specs [Pipeline Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching) indicating that caches are per agent. On the contrary, the spec talks about retrieving the cache from **the server**.

Comment: You can check out Timeline - Get rest api to get the task status of a previous build run. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598945/get-task-status-in-next-step/60611680?noredirect=1#comment107271078_60611680)